# What does Selenium use? Java or Javascript?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am a newbie. I am about to join a automation testing project that uses Selenium. All I want to know is what we use for developing test scripts? Java scripts? or Basic Java? Please answer .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE? HTML table based selenese language. Underlying javascript. Webdriver? Multiple supported languages. More information here: http://www.seleniumhq.org